# find nested array based on given value

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

```
var myarr = new Array([001,"Ravi",800000],[002,"John",700000],[003,"Vishal","500000"],
                      [004,"Michel",600000],[005,"Stella",700000]);
```

How to display one array from `myarr`? For example if I enter `002` in input box it should display: `002,"John",700000`

Comment: Can you change your original data structure to a map?  As it stands now, I think you'll have to iterate over the entire array and then check to see if an entry matches.

Comment: problem I see is that the first element in each array will be 1,2,3,4,5 not 001, 002, 003, 004, 005 ... because numbers - it'll make the search less obvious to someone who doesn't know how the basics of javascript work

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend changing your data structure to something resembling  a map.  Then you can print out each person's data using the number (or string representation thereof) as a key.  Something like this:

```
var data = {};
data["001"] = ["Ravi", 800000];
data["002"] = ["John", 700000];
data["003"] = ["Vishal", 500000];
data["004"] = ["Michel", 600000];
data["005"] = ["Stella", 700000];

var input = "002";
console.log(data[input]);
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: `print()`? Why introduce a non-standard function? `console.log()` works nicely with an [embedded, runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) directly in your answer...

Answer (score -1):

This is a classic example of Arrays inside an array.

If you want to display the entire array 002,"John",700000 then take an index of that array from the outer array.

e.g.

```
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myarr = new Array([001,"Ravi",800000],[002,"John",700000],[003,"Vishal","500000"],[004,"Michel",600000],[005,"Stella",700000]);

//This will display your entire second array.
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myarr[1];

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want a lookup to try key-value data structure in which your id will be key and the entire object will be value.

e.g.
var obj = {key1: value1, key2: value2};

Comment: *"If you want a lookup"* - Which is what the question is asking for, so shouldn't that be the focus of the answer?